# Accessing element in a dynamic-allocated list

Tags: c++, memory-management, dynamic, linked-list

So I have this piece of code recreating a hash table with separate chaining without STL (my assignment forbids it). Unfortunately, I can't modify any structures used. TElem is an int value, NULL_TELEM is a value that recognizes a null element, and elem is a value.

My problem occurs if I try to add more numbers with the same hashValue, like 7777 and 8777 if the hash function returns %100 of a number (the while marked with a comment is where the memory can' be accessed properly):

How can I get this to work?

(UPDATED)

For convenience purposes, I'll add a copy-pastable code, including the previous features (all in one file):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<assert.h>

typedef int TElem;

#define NULL_TELEM -111111

int hashFunction(TElem elem){

     return elem%100; //key: 1905, it returns 5
};

struct Node
        {
            TElem val=NULL_TELEM;
            Node* next;
    };

class Book {
private:
       unsigned int m;
       Node* nodes;

    public:
        Book() {
    m = 0;
    this->nodes = new Node[100];
    for(int i=0; i<100; i++)
    {
        nodes[i].val=NULL_TELEM;
        nodes[i].next=nullptr;
    }
};
        bool add(TElem elem){
    if(elem<1000 || elem>9999)
        return false;
    int hashValue = hashFunction(elem);
    if(nodes[hashValue].val==elem)
        return false;
    if(nodes[hashValue].next==nullptr && nodes[hashValue].val==NULL_TELEM)
    {
        nodes[hashValue].val = elem;
        m++;
        return true;
    }
    Node* b1=new Node;
    b1=nodes[hashValue].next;
    while (b1->val != elem && b1->val != NULL_TELEM)   //Here?? Exactly at this while
        b1=b1->next;
    if (b1->val != elem)
    {
        b1->next->val = elem;
        b1->next->next = nullptr;
        m++;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
};
};

int main()
{ Book b;
assert(b.add(7777)==true);
assert(b.add(8777)==true); //this is where it doesn't work
return 0;}
```

Comment: What problem occurs at the `while`? What makes you think the program doesn't work?

Comment: It seems like it can't access the memory. It doesn't work when I try to add more than a number with the same hash value (I got to a conclusion with testing all the possible situations)

Comment: Then please update the question with the cases that are failing. We need to be able to reproduce the error to help.

Comment: updated! Sorry for the inconvenience!

Comment: This is still not a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We should be able to copy-paste your code, and see the error.

Comment: Edited! Tried to put this in one file, so I hope it works!

Comment: This is much better. You're still missing the definition of `NULL_TELEM`, and `hashfunction`.

Comment: Added them too! I literally stressed you out so much tho-

Comment: Haha, no worries, I'm not stressed. Good edits, the bug is reproducible now :)

Comment: Hopefully, it works decently in a single (structured it like main for convenience) file. I'm used to working with more

Answer (score 0):

In this snippet:

```
Node* b1=new Node;
b1=nodes[hashValue].next;
while (b1->val != elem && b1->val != NULL_TELEM)   //Here?? Exactly at this while
    b1=b1->next;
if (b1->val != elem)
{
    b1->next->val = elem;
    b1->next->next = nullptr;
    m++;
    return true;
}
```

where you add to a particular linked list, has several issues. As soon as you allocate memory for `b1`, you overwrite that pointer, and leak memory. There are also issues with the logic of the insertion.

The following snippet inserts into the linked list corresponding to the hash value, and only inserts it if `elem` is not already there. I removed the check for `NULL_ELEM` since that seems redundant.

```
auto b1 = nodes + hashValue;
while (b1->next && b1->val != elem)  // the check for next is very important
    b1=b1->next;
if (b1->val != elem)    
{ 
    b1->next = new Node{elem, nullptr};
    m++;
    return true;
}
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/P6VCbT). It should work, if I understand the problem correctly. At least it doesn't segfault any longer.

Comment: you are literally a hero!!! Thanks for everything (especially your patience)!!!

Comment: @Kreatives No problem, happy to help :) In the future, try to follow the advice I gave when posting a question, and you'll get helped much faster. Also, if the answer solves your problem, then consider accepting it.